# Как изолировать php скрипт от глобальной области видимости?

Tags: php

Есть самописный фреймворк с единой точкой входа, чпу, роутингом и прочим. Возникла необходимость в одном из контроллеров запустить сторонний скрипт в данном случае Adminer.php (gui для управления mysql аналог phpmyadmin).

При подключении этого дела сыпятся ошибки `Cannot redeclare functionname()` потому что там очевидно глобально используются функции с теми же названиями.

Можно ли как-то изолировать (создать локальную область видимости) для этого скрипта от всего остального средствами PHP?

Comment: пространства имён, помогут?

Comment: дак в в целом то этот скрипт от фреймворка изолировать нельзя? фейрмворк в данном случае что-то полезное вообще делает? или просто запускает скрипт? Если просто запускает, и сам ничего не производит, то на уровне хтаксесса управление сразу отдавайте в этот скрипт а не во фреймворк.